# GetCurrentUser() is null after restarting Xamarin.forms app (Parse)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, parse-platform

I am developing a Xamarin.forms app, using the latest parse SDK for .NET. Parse-SDK.dotNET 2.0.0-develop-1.

Everything is working great except the sdk don’t sems to save the userobject and ParseInstallationobject to disk between restarts of the app. If you are logged in and restart the app, GetCurrentUser() is null, and a new installationObject is created.

I inizialize my ParseClient like this:

```
                var client = new ParseClient(new ServerConnectionData
                {
                    ApplicationID = "Application_ID",
                    Key = "NET_KEY",
                    ServerURI = "Server_URL"
                },
                    new LateInitializedMutableServiceHub(),
                    new MetadataMutator
                    {
                        EnvironmentData = new EnvironmentData { OSVersion = Environment.OSVersion.ToString(), Platform = Device.RuntimePlatform, TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName },
                        HostManifestData = new HostManifestData
                        {
                            Version = this.GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion,
                            Name = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name,
                            ShortVersion = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(),
                            Identifier = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
                        }
                    });
                client.Publicize();
```

I have tried to save the SessionToken myself, and retrieve the user like this:

`await ParseClient.Instance.BecomeAsync(sessionToken).ConfigureAwait(false);`

And it works, but I can’t find a solution to retrieve/save the ParseInstallationObject.

There are examples on gitHub with the same issue, https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/366 , but I can’t see that anyone have found a solution.

I have also tried to use the older sdk, but it doesn’t sems to be working with Xamarin.forms, or is there a way to use it?

Is there anyone who have found a working solution for the parse SDK and Xamarin.forms?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and debugging the complete sorce code for the SDK I finally found a solution that is working so far. You have to specify the path for the Cashe file, or the sdk will create a new one at every restart of the app. See the complete way to initialize the ParseClient below.

```
            client = new ParseClient(new ServerConnectionData
            {
                ApplicationID = Application_ID,
                Key = NET_KEY,
                ServerURI = Server_URL
            },
                new LateInitializedMutableServiceHub(),
                new MetadataMutator
                {
                    EnvironmentData = new EnvironmentData { OSVersion = Environment.OSVersion.ToString(), Platform = Device.RuntimePlatform, TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName },
                    HostManifestData = new HostManifestData
                    {
                        Version = this.GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion,
                        Name = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name,
                        ShortVersion = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(),
                        Identifier = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
                    },
                },
                new AbsoluteCacheLocationMutator
                {
                    CustomAbsoluteCacheFilePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/.local/share/Parse/_fallback/1866527620.cachefile"
                });
            client.Publicize();
```